# reading executable until next MZ

Tags: c#, .net

I can easily read an entire executable file, or however many bytes I'd like to read via defining the size but what about if I want to read it from the beginning up until the next "MZ" ? if 2 files are binded together and I want to grab the first half only, not knowing the size of it.

mz binary stuff 1 - the one i want
mz binary stuff 2

0x77, 0x90 == MZ

Comment: You do know that files can contain the string “MZ” perfectly fine without being concatenated PEs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take SizeOfRawData for each [IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680341%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ([pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER.html)) structure and append SizeOfHeaders from [IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32/64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680336%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure.

First you will need to take [IMAGE_DOS_HEADER](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/IMAGE_DOS_HEADER.html) structure from PE/PE+ file

After that, e_lfanew field will points you to [IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32/64](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/IMAGE_NT_HEADERS.html) structure. (If Magic == 0x10b -> PE. If Magic = 0x20b -> PE+ file)

Count of sectionHeadersCount you can get from [IMAGE_FILE_HEADER](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/IMAGE_FILE_HEADER.html) structure.

```
UInt32 startAddress = IMAGE_DOS_HEADER.e_lfanew + 4 + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IMAGE_FILE_HEADER)) + [IMAGE_FILE_HEADER][6].SizeOfOptionalHeader 

for(UInt32 loop = 0;loop < sectionHeadersCount;loop++)
{
    IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER section = /*Map offset to IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER structure Method*/(startAddress);
    startAddress += Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER));//Offset to next section
}

// Example of Mapping function:
public T PtrToStructure<T>(UInt32 offset) where T : struct
{
    Byte[] bytes = this.ReadBytes(offset, (UInt32)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)));

    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    try
    {
         T result = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(T));
         return result;
    } finally
    {
         handle.Free();
    }
}
```

[Detailed PE/PE+ description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx)